# Logic erorr, arrays and typedef

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with this code, it compiles it seems to run fine, but the average is not coming out correctly. I believe it has something to do with the typedef or the array. We are just learning arrays in my class and I am not very comfortable with typedef

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int numberT = 50;

typedef float temps[numberT];
float averageTemp(temps, int);

int main(){

    char answer;
    float average;

    int number;

    temps temperature;
    cout << "This program will take the temperatures "
         << "of consecutive days and average them " << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to start? (Press y)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'){

    cout << "How many temperatures do you want to input?" << endl;
    cin >> number;

        for(int x=0;x<number;x++){
            if(not(answer== 'n' || answer == 'N')){
                cout << "Please input temperature for day "
                     << x + 1 << endl;
                cin >> temperature[x];
            }
            else{
                cout << "You have stopped inputting temperatures";
                break;
            }
        }

    averageTemp(temperature, number);

    cout << endl << endl << "The average is " << average;


    }else
        cout << "No temperatures to average";


    return 0;

}


float averageTemp(temps array, int number){
    float sum=0;

    for(int x=0; x<number; x++){
        array[x];
        sum+=array[x];
    }

    float average = sum / number;

    return average;
}
```

Comment: Hi :D welcome to stackoverflow. On a side note I really don't recommend using typedef the way you did there. It is confusing and unreadable.

Comment: Thank you! Is it confusing because of my implementation of it, or is typedef just confusing in general? I was required to use it for this particular program.

Comment: No typedef is generally a very useful keyword. But the way it was used to refer to an array of fixed size is not very readable in my opinion (especially when you call it temps :D). typedef is usually meant to be used to simplify long and complicated types, for example instead of having to type `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` you'd simply typedef it to a simpler name like `MapOfVectors` or something like that.

Comment: In your case seeing a function that takes `temps` as an argument is confusing. On the other hand if I see the function taking `float array[]` I know right away that it takes an array of floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function:

```
float averageTemp(temps, int);
```

returns the average, but this line:

```
averageTemp(temperature, number);
```

is not using the return value for anything. You need to assign it:

```
average = averageTemp(temperature, number);
```

---

PS: Turn on warnings in your compilers, there is a line that doesn't do anything useful.